# how to get release date from mp3 using ID3 lib. in php

Tags: php, mp3, id3

I want to retrieve released date from ID3 library.
it gives me release year but not the release date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get release time using getId3 library, try following code :-

```
$getID3                     = new getID3;
$this->arrMp3Info           = $getID3->analyze($file);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($this->arrMp3Info);die;
```